# Random Effects Meta Analysis without Standard error

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis

I am trying to code up a random effects meta analysis in R. I was given some data and I noticed none of the data comes with Standard error. The only thing provided are the Risk ratios, Confidence intervals, sample sizes and number of events for different outcomes being examined for each study. Is there a way to run a random effects analysis on this using something like the `metafor` package? I'm fine with any package, but I've heard of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the risk ratio plus its confidence interval then (a) take logs of the RR and both limits of the CI(b) work out the standard error of the log RR from the width of the CI on the log scale, dividing by 4 should be close enough. That is it, you now have what metafor calls yi and sei

If you have further more programming type questions it would be better to ask them on the dedicated mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// You do need to register first. The authors of both metafor and the other main alternative, meta, all hang out there. Such questions would be strictly speaking off topic here.